# How to use Blender in a way that allows easy modifications

Tags: workflow

I am new to Blender
   I had just made my first 3d print job
question
suppose that my object is made of two basic objects
cube and cone
I had created a few duplications of these basic objects and then used a few union and diff operations.
Now that I got my 3d object printed
I realize that the cube should be smaller
I wish I could have change my first cube size and all other cube dimensions will change as well.

is there a method of work with Blender that allow that?
Thanks
Ori

Answer (score 1):

Try the same thing again. However this time don't apply the boolean modifier on your original object set, just keep them active. You can take your original objects by duplication and hide them on a different layer. This way if you need to make a modification, you can duplicate them back to your working layer, make the desired changes, and on the working layer only apply the modifier(s).

So that you have a bit more visual context to what this means, here is the break-down:

Here are the ways that I split up the layers:

Layer 1 (<kbd>Homerow 1</kbd>) = The Active Layer

Layer 2 (<kbd>Homerow 2</kbd>) = The Stored Object Being Subtracted From

Layer 11 (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Homerow 1</kbd>) = The Stored Object Being Subtracted.

Here are the screen shots in the order listed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the modification workflow after you find the need to change something:

[image]